# search EditText input online if it's not a URL

Tags: java, android, browser, android-edittext

I'm learning android coding using java language. currently, I'm working on a web browser, it has an EditText for giving the URL address but my problem is that I want it to also be a search bar for a search engine like google. so, for example, if the input doesn't end with a domain like ".com", the app automatically searches the input with google or any other search engine.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Patterns.WEB_URL to verify the EditText input, whether it's a proper url or not.

```
boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    return Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()
}
```

You can call this function passing EditText text as the URL.

```
String url = editText.getText().toString()
if(isValidUrl(url))
  //load url
else
  // search the text using any search engine like https://www.google.com/search?q=url
```

Comment: Could you do the code in java, I can't understand Kotlin.